# How to skip Cloudinary popup for Uploading while using Cloudinary UI widget

Tags: cloudinary

[image]

We are using Cloudinary UI widget.

When the user clicks on a button to upload, we show this widget.
Once, the user clicks on the select file button, window dialog is open for selection of files.

But, is there any way to bypass this popup & directly make the user click on select file button programmatically by means of any Cloudinary upload UI parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the widget in a div. For example-

```
<h2>Make sure to update cloud_name and upload_preset.</h2>
<div id="inline_container"></div>
<div id="thumbnails"></div>

cloudinary.openUploadWidget( 
  {     
   cloud_name: 'cloud_name', 
   upload_preset: 'upload_preset', 
   cropping: 'server',
   multiple: false,
   max_files: 1,
   thumbnails: '#thumbnails',
   inline_container: "#inline_container",
   keep_widget_open: false,
   cropping_show_dimensions: true,
   sources: ['local']
  },
  function(error, result) { 
    console.log(error, result);
    if (result != null)
        $('#inline_container').html(""); // Will remove the widget after successful upload
  }
);
```